# Start a long-running program over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

I have a Virtual Machine that is running Ubuntu, and I can SSH into the Virtual Machine just fine. I can even start my python program over SSH using the following:

```
python foldername/app.py
```

I am on a Windows machine, using Git Bash to SSH. If I start my python program this, way I have to leave the Git Bash window open. How can I start the python program without having to leave the Git Bash open on my Windows machine? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure of the best tool/approach, nor am I sure this is the best site for the question, but none of the approaches I can think of are at all specific to Python.

Comment: Take a look at `screen(1)`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Lol4t0: I would agree, but we don't seem to have a migration path to unix.SE, and I feel like it wouldn't be very courteous to asker or answerers to ask them to start over when we could just migrate it to superuser.com where it is (unless they've changed the rules?) on-topic

Comment: @SamB, the thing is that we do not have migration path to unix@linux because 'nobody wants to migrate to unix@linux anyway'. You can search meta for this issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use `nohup`:

```
nohup python foldername/app.py &
```

now you can close your connection and the program will keep running. You can find more information [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Comment: nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’ -- I got that when I tried running the command?

Comment: @antfuentes87, That's ok

Comment: @Lol4t0 Yeah, it seems like it is, just gives me a error when I try to close out of the Git Bash, but I can see that program is still working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use a virtual terminal, e.g:

- [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)
- [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/)

Both of them should be available via the ubuntu package manager.

Then (after logging in via ssh) issue the following commands:

- screen
- python myprog.py
- CTRL+A D

or for tmux

- tmux
- python myprog.py
- CTRL+B D

Then you can close your ssh connection and look at the output when you return later by typing `screen attach` or `tmux attach`

I'd personally recommend using tmux.

Answer (score 0):

Two main approaches come to my mind, depending on what you are up to:

1. Make the program run as a [daemon](/questions/tagged/daemon) (a program that runs in the background, not connected to any terminal); if appropriate (and logistically feasible), configure the system-wide [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) system to start it.
2. Alternatively, just run the program under a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) program (like [GNU screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)) that implements a persistent virtual terminal that you can attach to/detach from as needed.