# Attempting to run a Discord bot

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, discord

As the title states, I am trying to run a Discord bot during the 12-month trial. I am able to host it for a short period of time by going into the Node.js VM instance and launching it with `node app.js`, as I normally would in console locally. It shuts down a short while after I exit out of the SSH connection. Is there any way to fix that so the process runs as long as the VM is online? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start a long-running program over SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842173/start-a-long-running-program-over-ssh)

Comment: you can also use https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PM2, screen, tmux, or many other choices.
You can find a short list of terminal multiplexers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer#Implementations).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [PM2](http://pm2.io/), forever or [strongloop](http://www.strongloop.com/) for run your script.